# Error in integrating Facebook+Parse in Android app

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform

Here is my code to integrate Facebook with Android app (parse.com) .

Please find below the code and stack trace.here trying to authenticate FB user from parse.

When you click on `login with Facebook` option application crashes. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

```
private void onLoginButtonClicked() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LoginActivity.this.progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(
                LoginActivity.this, "", "Logging in...", true);
        List<String> permissions = Arrays.asList("basic_info", "user_about_me",
                "user_relationships", "user_birthday", "user_location");

        // ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(appId);
        ParseFacebookUtils.logIn(permissions, this, new LogInCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) {
                LoginActivity.this.progressDialog.dismiss();
                if (user == null) {
                    Log.d(IntegratingFacebookTutorialApplication.TAG,
                            " user cancelled the Facebook login.");
                } else if (user.isNew()) {
                    Log.d(IntegratingFacebookTutorialApplication.TAG,
                            "User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
                    showUserDetailsActivity();
                } else {
                    Log.d(IntegratingFacebookTutorialApplication.TAG,
                            "User logged in through Facebook!");
                    showUserDetailsActivity();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

logs

```
    09-24 18:33:35.809: E/AndroidRuntime(641): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-24 18:33:35.809: E/AndroidRuntime(641): java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must call ParseFacebookUtils.initialize() before using ParseFacebookUtils
09-24 18:33:35.809: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils.checkInitialization(ParseFacebookUtils.java:88)
09-24 18:33:35.809: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils.logIn(ParseFacebookUtils.java:331)
09-24 18:33:35.809: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils.logIn(ParseFacebookUtils.java:355)
09-24 18:33:35.809: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at com.tukutane.LoginActivity.onLoginButtonClicked(LoginActivity.java:168)
09-24 18:33:35.809: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at com.tukutane.LoginActivity.onClick(LoginActivity.java:154)
09-24 18:33:35.809: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
09-24 18:33:35.809: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
09-24 18:33:35.809: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
09-24 18:33:35.809: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-24 18:33:35.809: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-24 18:33:35.809: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
09-24 18:33:35.809: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-24 18:33:35.809: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-24 18:33:35.809: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
09-24 18:33:35.809: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-24 18:33:35.809: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 3):

you have to call this

```
ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(appId);
```

before

```
ParseFacebookUtils.logIn();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
09-24 18:33:35.809: E/AndroidRuntime(641): java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must call ParseFacebookUtils.initialize() before using ParseFacebookUtils
```

Did you initialize parse tools before calling login?
At least the log file you've shared says you didn't do that.

Make a call to following method:

```
ParseFacebookUtils.initialize()
```

You're calling

```
Parse.Initialize()
```

Comment: tied this in onCreate();
Parse.initialize(this, "ASFolIoL4cWIs7pxHzbGOLR0Kj0LQ7f1tQGh4HwR",
    "8HXvQPTaSQWuUJKjJyn6OMFU1snfL8iO8qX0HmKJ");
  ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());
anything else??

Comment: @user1987430 you did Parse.initialize() NOT ParseFacebookUtils.initialize()

Comment: @user1987430 FYI, I know it's six months late or so, but you should never ever ever leave your app ID/Client key in a message like that. Could be a real bad time if someone gets ahold of that, and they wanna play a prank/act maliciously on your app.

Comment: As a general note for anyone that comes across this page, your IDs/Secrets for all apps should never be used on a SO question, and more so shouldn't be committed to a public GitHub repo, etc. This includes Amazon S3 buckets, etc.

Comment: keykeykeykeykekeykeykeykey instead of real values will do

Answer (score 0):

Use a Application class like this

```
public class SampleApp extends Application {


private static String PARSE_APPLICATION_ID;
private static String PARSE_CLIENT_KEY;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    PARSE_APPLICATION_ID = getResources().getString(R.string.PARSE_APPLICATION_ID);
    PARSE_CLIENT_KEY = getResources().getString(R.string.PARSE_CLIENT_KEY);
    Log.d(tag, "initializing with keys");
    // Add your initialization code here
    Parse.initialize(this, PARSE_APPLICATION_ID, PARSE_CLIENT_KEY);
    // This allows read access to all objects
    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();

    defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
    defaultACL.setPublicWriteAccess(true);

    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);

    Log.d(tag, "initializing app complete");
}
}
```

Add this in manifest

i Hope this will clear the error.

Comment: Why would you add this in manifest? It should be in a separate class like Man.java

Answer (score 0):

For everybody that gets this exception double check that you are actually using your custom application class by specifying it in the manifest under the application tag :)

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name=".CustomApplicationClassName">
```